# Create docker from tar with Python Docker API

Tags: python, docker, docker-api

I want to use a remote docker host to build an image from an in memory tar with the Python Docker API.

I have successfully created a docker image when sending just a Dockerfile like so:

```
client.images.build(fileobj=BytesIO(dockerfile_str.encode("utf-8"))
                    tag="some_image_name",
                    encoding="utf-8")
```

However, when I try to set `custom_context=True` and pass a `tar archive` according to the [documentation](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/images.html) it fails with the error:

```
docker.errors.APIError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error ("Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile")
```

This is how I try to do it:

```
with tarfile.open(fileobj=BytesIO(), mode="w") as tar:
    dockerfile_str = """
        FROM ubuntu

        ENTRYPOINT ["printf", "Given command is %s"]

        CMD ["not given"]
    """.encode("utf-8")

    dockerfile_tar_info = tarfile.TarInfo("Dockerfile")
    dockerfile_tar_info.size = len(dockerfile_str)

    tar.addfile(dockerfile_tar_info, BytesIO(dockerfile_str))

    client = docker.DockerClient("some_url")
    client.images.build(fileobj=tar.fileobj,
                        custom_context=True,
                        dockerfile="Dockerfile",
                        tag="some_image_name",
                        encoding="utf-8")
    client.close()
```

EDIT:

If I take the route over disk with:

```
...
with tarfile.open("tmp_1.tar", mode="w") as tar:
...
client.images.build(fileobj=tarfile.open("tmp_1.tar", mode="r").fileobj,
...
```

I instead get the following error message:

```
docker.errors.APIError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error ("archive/tar: invalid tar header")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. I found the solution. I had to call `.getvalue()` on `fileobj`.

```
with tarfile.open(fileobj=BytesIO(), mode="w") as tar:
    dockerfile_str = """
        FROM ubuntu

        ENTRYPOINT ["printf", "Given command is %s"]

        CMD ["not given"]
    """.encode("utf-8")

    dockerfile_tar_info = tarfile.TarInfo("Dockerfile")
    dockerfile_tar_info.size = len(dockerfile_str)

    tar.addfile(dockerfile_tar_info, BytesIO(dockerfile_str))

    client = docker.DockerClient("some_url")
    client.images.build(fileobj=tar.fileobj.getvalue(),
                        custom_context=True,
                        dockerfile="Dockerfile",
                        tag="some_image_name",
                        encoding="utf-8")
    client.close()
```